# Вывод динамического двумерного массива в определенном порядке

Tags: массивы, динамические-массивы

Нужно написать код, который бы выполнял обход двумерного динамического массива в определенном порядке как показано на картинке.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Основа программы

```
#include "pch.h" 
#include <iostream> 
#include <math.h> 
#include <iomanip> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int  n, i, j, k, l;
    cout << "введите размерность массива" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    int m = n * n;
    int* b = new int[n*n];
    int** Mas = new int *[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        Mas[i] = new int[n];

    cout << "Enter\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cin >> Mas[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << Mas[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    // тут нужно присвоить массиву b значения из двумерного массива Mas как показано на картинке
    cout << "полученный массив" << endl;
    for (int H = 0; H < m; H++)
    {
        cout << b[H];
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Извините, а кто должен написать код?

Comment: А известна глубина массива?